# How to rearrange virtual desktops in windows 10 home?

Tags: windows-10

I want to rearrange virtual desktops in windows but when I right click on the virtual desktop icon no other options are mentioned except "rename" .

[image]

Comment: I am fairly sure you cannot do this except perhaps to find some third party software that will do this for you. That said, I do not know of such software.

Comment: Have you tried the standard `drag and drop` movement to reorganize the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reorder virtual desktops in windows 11
(not available in Windows 10):

- Hover over the Task View button on the taskbar to show all desktops
- Right-click the desktop to be moved to show its context-menu
- Use the context-menu.

[image]

Comment: Tried, not working.

Comment: This option didn't make to Windows 10 version 21H2. Unfortunately, it's only available in Windows 11.

Comment: That method does not work on my Windows 10 VM or my Windows 11 Host machine.

Comment: @John: I fired up my Windows 11 VM and found that everything has changed, as usual. So I rewrote my answer.

Comment: Agreed. It is a bit picky but I was able to make it work. It won't save me 10 minutes a year, so I would never use this.